# matching and marking ones that are duplicates in excel

Tags: excel, relational-database

I have two tables in excel

first table has product list with an id

```
product_id   |  package_size   | package_name
1            |  40             | product 1
2            |  100            | product 2
2            |  100            | product 2
2            |  50             | product 2
3            |  100            | product 3
3            |  100            | product 3
```

second table has two columns:

```
product_id   |  multiple_package_size
1            |  multiple_package_size
2            |  multiple_package_size
3            |  multiple_package_size
```

What I am expecting to return on the second table is this:

```
product_id   |  multiple_package_size
1            | 
2            |           x
3            |
```

right now my multiple_package_size column is empty, I am trying to put an x on every product id that has multiple package size. I have been using INDEX MATCH but it is not flagging every product that has multiple package size.
Here is the formula that I have in the multiple_package_size column now:

```
=if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,0)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,1)),if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,1)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,2)),if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,2)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,3)),if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,3)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,4)),if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,4)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,5)),if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,5)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,6)),if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,6)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,7)),if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,7)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,8)),if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,8)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,9)),,"x"),"x"),"x"),"x"),"x"),"x"),"x"),"x"),"x")
```

for easy read:

```
=if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,0)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,1)),
if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,1)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,2)),
if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,2)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,3)),
if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,3)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,4)),
if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,4)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,5)),
if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,5)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,6)),
if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,6)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,7)),
if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,7)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,8)),
if(INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,8)) = INDEX(Sheet3!$E$1:$E$89999,MATCH(A29,Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,9)),
,"x")
,"x")
,"x")
,"x")
,"x")
,"x")
,"x")
,"x")
,"x")
```

What am I doing wrong? is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to check with `COUNTIF`

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999,A29) > 1, "x", "")
```

> What am I doing wrong?

Probably misunderstand the third parameter of the `MATCH` function.

---

If the first table has duplicate rows, which wasn't visible in your first question, it's a little more complicated:

```
=IF(AGGREGATE(14,6,Sheet3!$I$1:$I$89999/(Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999=A29),1)<>
    AGGREGATE(15,6,Sheet3!$I$1:$I$89999/(Sheet3!$A$1:$A$89999=A29),1),"x", "")
```

Basically it compares the maximum and minimum package sizes of the matched product id, and if they're different it marks the "x".

p.s. I'm not completely sure that the columns correspond exactly to your data I only tried to guess them from your formula. I assumed that product ID is sheet3 column A, the package size is sheet3 column I and the value searched for is A29. Adjust them if needed.

p.s.2 I think you should consider simply removing the duplicates from your data if that's an option.

Comment: this will not do it. It will return both product 2 and 3 with an x.. when product 3 has the two different entries with the same package size. 
I also have two different sheets here and I want to check if that specific product_id has more than multiple package size that is why I am using the match function.

Comment: @shnisaka ok. It wasn't clear that the first table has duplicates before you edited the question. I will see how to take that into account and come back to you.

Comment: sorry I was styling it to make it look nicer and easier to read =)